# Can I use the Umbraco CMS with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, umbraco

Recently, I heard of Umbraco. Can I use it in PHP? Is it like WordPress? Please give me good points about the Umbraco CMS and any advantages/disadvantages.

Comment: Edit your question to this: "Can I use Umbraco in PHP? Is it like Wordpress? Please give me advice on the Umbraco CMS and any advantages/disadvantages. Thanks in advance."

Comment: @Jake i am not from english background, you might listen that there are other languages also existed in this world ... please answer if you know the answer, I don't want you english suggestion.

Comment: since you aren't a native speaker, you should take the advice of those who are. It will help your questions get answered faster/better. Guess how fast your question will get closed if you answer in Punjabi, Pashto, Sindhi, or Balochi? Take the suggestion to heart.

Answer (score 3):

> Few days back i listen about umbraco, can i use it in PHP?

No. Umbraco is written in C#. From the [Wikipedia article:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbraco)

> Umbraco is an open source content management system (CMS) platform for publishing content on the World Wide Web and intranets. It is written in C# and deployed on Microsoft based infrastructure. The open source backend is released under an MIT License while the UI is released under the Umbraco license[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbraco).

Answer (score 1):

No PHP at this point, but it does accept any of the Iron* languages from Microsoft.  For example, IronPython.